# Gas engine on a robot: Is is possible? Is it a good idea?

Tags: robotics

For a college project, a group of us are trying to design a remote controlled snowblower. We want to go with a battery and a gas engine basically like a car. Our logic for this was batteries wouldn't last long enough without being too large/heavy/costly and an electric cord would probably get tangled and cut and might not be long enough.

We have some MechEs working on the mechanics of the thing but us EEs got stuck with the drivetrain and control side.

I've worked with robotics before (FIRST FRC in highschool and other college stuff) but I've never touched a gas engine of any sort. I'm having a little trouble with finding information on this topic and I expect its because I'm just not searching for the right things.

I'm wondering if anyone here has worked on systems like this in the past and can offer advice on where to start, any important things to consider or just general comments on the project.

Thank you!

Comment: I think Boston Dynamics did something like this on one of their robots, but they probably won't tell you how because of military use and stuff.

Comment: Boston Dynamics did indeed do this, on their "big dog" robot platform. @Arsenal

Comment: Cool! I'll see if I can get any more info on their work.

Comment: If operating on public streets, this sounds a lot like a self-driving car (if modified stock car) or a remote controlled hot rod (if built from scratch). Big can of worms if you run afoul of the department of motor vehicles.

Comment: @MarkU: a snowblower isn't much bigger than a large lawnmower. No one is going to care.

Comment: Google operates a fleet of self-driving cars here in mountain view CA ( on public streets), and they always carry a trained human in the front seat, as a failsafe. Since you're using remote control, how will you prevent runaway in case of control malfunction?

Comment: ...what is this "snow" you speak of?  ☺

Comment: There were some battlebots that used gas engines: http://battlebots.wikia.com/wiki/Jaws_of_Death and http://twilightfoundry.com/2014/06/10-literal-worst-battlebots-of-all-time/

Answer (score 2):

[Something like this from walmart](http://www.walmart.com/ip/PowerPro-Technologies-2-Stroke-1000-Watt-Gasoline-Generator/39100842) is a good example of something you could use, and it even has a handy 12VDC output, 1000 Watts max generator with a 4L fuel tank. Please be aware that the 12VDC output only has 8.3A available, meaning it's only 100W. Your next bet to use more of the power from this would be to use a 1000W AC->DC converter (which you would need to buy) to get the most out of it. The 12VDC can go to an automotive SLA battery bank too.

Otherwise, you can try to do it from a motor and alternator:
Just get a small 2 stroke motor/generator, and bolt it to your machine, and the drive train output goes directly to an alternator (you can buy these or salvage from a car). The alternator DC output goes to the 12V automotive SLA battery bank on your mobile machine.

The alternator will charge the batteries, while the batteries and also power directly from the alternator (unless you use some diodes to block this from happening) can go to power whatever you want in your robotic snowblower.

Any converter you use should be automotive rated, and should be able to handle the crazy noise and over voltage spikes on the output of the alternator.

Comment: I mean depending on budget they could just buy a small 1kW generator and a power supply. It'd be cleaner, they wouldn't have to deal with the mechanics, and the electrical output would be a whole lot nicer.

Comment: @michaelyoyo yeah the last part of my answer actually suggests that, I might make that more apparent. The first section is if they wanted to actually use a random motor and drive shaft to turn an alternator and get raw electricity from that. I think the small generator for $140 with 100W DC output is the easiest and cleanest they can get, with an awesome price honestly.

Answer (score 2):

Well power wise you could use an alternator but for a college project that might be overkill.  I'd start with one or two of those little 6V batteries they use for riding lawnmowers (or motorcylces).  That solves your power problem for the electronics.

[image]

Then assuming you are working with your mechanical guys you'll want some form of electronic clutch like the one in this [link](http://letsmakerobots.com/content/electronic-clutch) Also googling "robot electronic clutch" brought up a bunch more results.

[image]

Something like that on both rear tires would give you forward, backwards and turning ability.  That's just an example, you could use any combination of electric motors, solenoids, or whatever to achieve the same effect.  Basically you're just trying to build an electro mechanical linkage.  I'm reminded of an old self propelled lawnmower that just lowered geared teeth onto the tracks of the rear wheels when it wanted to move forward.  You could easily automate something like that with a pair of motors.

Anyway just some ideas to get you going.  If I was doing the project that's how I'd think about it.  Where am I getting power from, how can I control the wheels for forward, backward, steering and idle, then I'd move on to sensors and navigation once I had my underlying platform working.  In fact I wouldn't even worry too much about the control electronics until I could manually get this to work.

Although depending on your team size maybe someone can work on control while someone else brings up the drive train.  Just like a real engineering project :)

Comment: I wonder if lead-acid batteries may have an issue with the extreme cold of actually blowing snow. Fully-charged, the electrolyte should be good to -20°C or just under freezing. An alternative might be supercaps. Take a look at what [this guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8miq6sDy0wA) is able to do with them. For blowing snow, just connect a "charger" to the caps, charge them up, and they'll be good for a few hours at least. Very lightweight and they work down to [-40°C](http://www.maxwell.com/images/documents/bcseries_ds_1017105-4.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

Not much beats the energy density of gasoline so it makes a lot of sense. You can buy a small gas powered generator for about $100 and just use it like it was mains power (limited to maybe 700-800W). For indoor testing, use the actual mains through an umbilical.

[image: harbor freight photo]

Comment: Just wanted to say that this is an excellent solution, Electrical motors are much more controllable than combustion fueled drive systems, and using a generator such as above will provide ample power for even high capacity motors without the hassles of dealing with designing an IC drive system.